# lua function not returning data

Tags: mobile, lua, coronasdk

I am having trouble with a Lua function. I can set the return value for sendAction to a string ("test") and it will return properly. However I can't get the variable of "data" to return as it always returns nil. What am i doing wrong?

```
local json = require("json");
local action = {};
local action_mt = { __index = action }

---------PRIVATE FUNCTIONS------------

function action:sendAction(values, networkListener)
    local data,pos,msg = "";
    local params = {}; params.body = "";
    for key,value in pairs(values) do
        params.body = params.body .. "&" .. key .."=" .. value
    end

    local function networkListener( event )
        if ( event.isError ) then
            print( "Network error!" );
        else
            data,pos,msg = json.decode( event.response );
            if (data.errors.count > 0) then
                print("errors");
            end
        end
        return data;
    end

    network.request( "http://127.0.0.1/action.php", "POST", networkListener, params )
end

------PUBLIC FUNCTIONS------
function action:new(action) 
    local newAction = { action = action };
    return setmetatable( newAction, action_mt )
end

function action:createSession()
    local data = action:sendAction( { action = "createSession" } );
    print(data);
end

return action;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sendAction` contains no return statement (in its scope). Why would you *expect* it to return anything?

The call to `network.request` is *asynchronous*, meaning the request actually happens in a separate thread of execution that runs parallel to your main code execution, so the request to the server and response from the server will happen after `sendAction` has returned.

You want to use the same model `network.request` does. That is, you pass a callback to `sendAction` which receives results when they become available. That's a very typical pattern for asynchronous code.

```
function action:sendAction(values, onSendActionComplete)
    local params = {}; params.body = "";
    for key,value in pairs(values) do
        params.body = params.body .. "&" .. key .."=" .. value
    end

    local function networkListener( event )
        if event.isError then
            onSendActionComplete(false, "Network error.");
        else
            local data,pos,msg = json.decode( event.response );
            if data.errors.count > 0 then
                onSendActionComplete(false, "JSON decode error.");
            else
                onSendActionComplete(true, data);
            end
        end
    end

    network.request( "http://127.0.0.1/action.php", "POST", networkListener, params )
end

------PUBLIC FUNCTIONS------
function action:new(action) 
    local newAction = { action = action };
    return setmetatable( newAction, action_mt )
end

function action:createSession()
    local function onSendActionComplete(success, data)
        if success then
            print(data);
        else
            print('Error:', data)
        end
    end
    action:sendAction( { action = "createSession" }, onSendActionComplete)
end
```

Comment: This code still returns nil and i know there is a proper response cause i can print the original response and get the json from server as expected.

Comment: Update: I changed this part: onSendActionComplete(true, data); to onSendActionComplete(true, json.decode(event.response));  This seems to work for some reason, I'm assuming because the scope of data? (Update: Yes, it was the scope of data, i moved the var to the main block of the event listener and it now works. Thanks much @Mud